# Request and response with Angular $post and PHP Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I have a problem when I am sending data to Codeigniter via Angular $post. I am using this JS code:

```
 $scope.user.first_name = 'first name';
 $scope.user.last_name = 'last name';

 $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/registration',
      data: {user: $.param($scope.user)},
      headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
      }
 }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                 console.log(response)
         }, function errorCallback(response) {
                 console.log(response);
 });
```

My PHP is based from another answer from StackOverflow, but still doesn't work:

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($this->input->post());
```

, but in this way I see response empty array, if I say:

```
var_dump($this->input->post('user'));
```

I see response NULL, Same is and with:

```
var_dump(json_encode($this->input->post()));
```

with or without key "user". Even if I use:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

for the response I get empty array.

How to send and get data via $post Angular service with Codeigniter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send as form encoded data you need to serialize the whole data object with `$.param()`

Change:

```
 data: {user: $.param($scope.user)},
```

To

```
 data: $.param(angular.copy({user: $scope.user})),
```

Or use [`$httpParamSerializerJQLike`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

If you use defaults of `$http` would just be

```
 $http.post( '/registration',$scope.user).then(...
```

And in php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: Still the response is an object with data NULL.

Comment: With your code, but not defaults. And with this PHP  `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));var_dump(json_encode($data));` - it returns string NULL, without `json_encode` is just NULL. I see in dev tools that the request is sended via browser.

Comment: because you need to use same content type on both ends. If you send form encoded need to use `$_POST` or `$this->input->post()` and if you send as json per defaults use `file_get_contents`

Comment: Thx a lot :), now with `var_dump($this->input->post('user'));` it works fine.